# spring boot jwt (signup , login)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jwt

I'm trying to implement membership registration and login logic using jwt in spring boot. When I ran the login logic, it was confirmed that user information was stored in the DB and searched, but when I sent a request to log in, the error kept saying that the password did not match. I'd like to know the cause and solution. It hasn't been long since I started developing it, so I'd appreciate it if you could explain it in detail

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    private final JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String token = resolveToken((HttpServletRequest) request);

        if (token != null && jwtTokenProvider.validateToken(token)) {
            Authentication authentication = jwtTokenProvider.getAuthentication(token);
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private String resolveToken(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String bearerToken = request.getHeader("Authorization");


        if (StringUtils.hasText(bearerToken) && bearerToken.startsWith("Bearer")) {
            return bearerToken.substring(7);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

```
@Slf4j
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class JwtTokenProvider {
    private final JwtProperties jwtConfig;
    private final MemberRepository memberRepository;
    private final SignatureAlgorithm signatureAlgorithm = SignatureAlgorithm.HS256;
    private Key signingKey;
    private JwtParser jwtParser;
    //todo 배포시 변경해야함
//    private static final Long ACCESS_TOKEN_PERIOD = 1000L * 60L * 60L; // 1시간
    private static final Long ACCESS_TOKEN_PERIOD = 1000L * 60L * 60L * 24L * 14L; // 2주
    private static final Long REFRESH_TOKEN_PERIOD = 1000L * 60L * 60L * 24L * 14L; // 2주

    @PostConstruct
    protected void init() {
        String secretKey = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(jwtConfig.getSecretKey().getBytes());
        byte[] apiKeySecretBytes = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(secretKey);
        signingKey = new SecretKeySpec(apiKeySecretBytes, signatureAlgorithm.getJcaName());
        jwtParser = Jwts.parserBuilder().setSigningKey(signingKey).build();
    }

    @Transactional
    public GeneratedTokenDTO generateToken(Authentication authentication) {
        String authorities = authentication.getAuthorities().stream()
                .map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(","));

        long now = (new Date()).getTime();

        Date accessTokenExpire = new Date(now + 86400000);
        String accessToken = Jwts.builder()
                .setSubject(authentication.getName())
                .claim("auth", authorities)
                .setExpiration(accessTokenExpire)
                .signWith(signingKey, signatureAlgorithm)
                .compact();

        String refreshToken = Jwts.builder()
                .setExpiration(new Date(now + (86400000L * 48 * 7)))
                .signWith(signingKey, SignatureAlgorithm.HS256)
                .compact();

        return GeneratedTokenDTO.builder()
                .grantType("Bearer")
                .accessToken(accessToken)
                .refreshToken(refreshToken)
                .build();

    }
    public Authentication getAuthentication(String accessToken) {
        Claims claims = parseClaims(accessToken);
        if (claims.get("auth") == null) {
            throw new BusinessException(ErrorCode.NO_PERMISSION);
        }

        Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities =
                Arrays.stream(claims.get("auth").toString().split(","))
                        .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());


        UserDetails principal = new User(claims.getSubject(), "", authorities);
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(principal, "", authorities);
    }

    public boolean validateToken(String token) {
        try {
            Jwts.parserBuilder().setSigningKey(signingKey).build().parseClaimsJws(token);
            return true;
        } catch (io.jsonwebtoken.security.SecurityException | MalformedJwtException e) {
            log.info("Invalid JWT Token", e);
        } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
            log.info("Expired JWT Token", e);
        } catch (UnsupportedJwtException e) {
            log.info("Unsupported JWT Token", e);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            log.info("JWT claims string is empty.", e);
        }
        return false;
    }

    private Claims parseClaims(String accessToken) {
        try {
            return Jwts.parserBuilder().setSigningKey(signingKey).build().parseClaimsJws(accessToken).getBody();
        } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
            return e.getClaims();
        }
    }
}
```

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class AuthServiceImpl implements AuthService{

    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder;
    private final MemberRepository memberRepository;
    private final AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder;
    private final JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;


    @Transactional
    public SignUpResponseDTO signUp(SignUpRequestDTO signUpRequestDTO ) {
        Optional<Member> findStudentId = memberRepository.findByStudentId(signUpRequestDTO.getStudentId());
        if (findStudentId.isPresent()) {
            throw new BusinessException(ErrorCode.MEMBER_PROFILE_DUPLICATION);
        }
        String hashedPassword = encoder.encode(signUpRequestDTO.getPassword());
        Member member = Member.builder()
                .name(signUpRequestDTO.getName())
                .studentId(signUpRequestDTO.getStudentId())
                .password(hashedPassword)
                .build();


        memberRepository.save(member);
        return SignUpResponseDTO.builder()
                .name(member.getName())
                .studentId(member.getStudentId())
                .build();
    }

@Transactional
public GeneratedTokenDTO login(String studentId, String password) {
    Optional<Member> optionalMember = memberRepository.findByStudentId(studentId);

    Member member = optionalMember.orElseThrow(() -> new BusinessException(ErrorCode.MEMBER_NOT_FOUND));

    if (!encoder.matches(password, member.getPassword())) {
        throw new BusinessException(ErrorCode.INVALID_PASSWORD);
    }

    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(studentId, password);
    Authentication authentication = authenticationManagerBuilder.getObject().authenticate(authenticationToken);
    GeneratedTokenDTO generatedTokenDTO = jwtTokenProvider.generateToken(authentication);

    return generatedTokenDTO;
}

}
```

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig{

    private final JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .sessionManagement(sessionManagement -> sessionManagement.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .formLogin(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .httpBasic(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> {
                    auth.requestMatchers("/**").permitAll();
                })
                .addFilterBefore(new JwtAuthenticationFilter(jwtTokenProvider), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return httpSecurity.build();

    }
}
```

```
@Getter
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
public class GeneratedTokenDTO {
    private String grantType;
    private String accessToken;
    private String refreshToken;
    @Setter
    private Boolean isRegistered;
}
```

```
@SuperBuilder
@Getter
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "member")
public class Member extends BaseEntity {


    @Column(length = 20,nullable = false)
    private String name;
    @Column(length = 9,unique = true,nullable = false)
    private String studentId;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "username",fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<MemberAndOrganization> organizations;
    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy ="reservationName" ,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Reservation> reservations;
    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy ="reservationName" ,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<ConfirmedReservation> confirmedReservations;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "writer",fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<PubComment> pubComments;
    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "writer",fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<BoothComment> boothComments;

    @Column
    private String refreshToken;

    public void setRefreshToken(String refreshToken) {
        this.refreshToken = refreshToken;
    }

    public void registerUser(String name, String studentId, String password) {
        this.name = name;
        this.studentId = studentId;
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

```
   @RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
@RequestMapping("/auth")
public class AuthController {
    private final AuthService authService;
    private final JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;

    @PostMapping("/signup")
    public ResponseEntity<SignUpResponseDTO> signUp(@RequestBody SignUpRequestDTO signUpRequestDTO) {

        SignUpResponseDTO responseDTO = authService.signUp(signUpRequestDTO);
        System.out.println("responseDTO = " + responseDTO);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(responseDTO);
    }

    @PostMapping("login")
    public GeneratedTokenDTO login(@RequestBody LoginRequestDTO loginRequestDTO) {
        String studentId = String.valueOf(loginRequestDTO.getStudentId());
        String password = String.valueOf(loginRequestDTO.getPassword());
        log.info("test1");
        GeneratedTokenDTO generatedTokenDTO = authService.login(studentId, password);
        log.info("test2");
        return generatedTokenDTO;

    }
}
```

```
2024-03-21T17:25:09.276+09:00 ERROR 2194 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] c.J.C.g.error.GlobalExceptionHandler     : handleEntityNotFoundException

org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: 자격 증명에 실패하였습니다.
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:141) ~[spring-security-core-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:182) ~[spring-security-core-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at com.JJoINT.CamPuzl.global.auth.service.AuthServiceImpl.login(AuthServiceImpl.java:64) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:351) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:765) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:385) ~[spring-tx-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:765) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:717) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at com.JJoINT.CamPuzl.global.auth.service.AuthServiceImpl$$SpringCGLIB$$0.login(<generated>) ~[main/:na]
    at com.JJoINT.CamPuzl.global.auth.controller.AuthController.login(AuthController.java:32) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:261) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:189) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:917) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:829) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1089) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:914) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:6.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:108) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.lambda$doFilterInternal$3(FilterChainProxy.java:231) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:365) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:131) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:85) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:179) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at com.JJoINT.CamPuzl.global.auth.jwt.JwtAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(JwtAuthenticationFilter.java:30) ~[main/:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:113) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerMappingIntrospector.lambda$createCacheFilter$3(HandlerMappingIntrospector.java:195) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:113) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:74) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebMvcSecurityConfiguration$CompositeFilterChainProxy.doFilter(WebMvcSecurityConfiguration.java:225) ~[spring-security-config-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:340) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1744) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

I tried various things using gpt, but all failed, and once I try to log in under the assumption that the membership logic is normal, the goal is to return the access token and refresh token along with the ok after verification

Comment: There seems to be no problem with the use of encoder's encode and matches.
I need more detailed information.
It would be a good idea to update the error log and controller's code.

Comment: @soonhankwon Thank you for your comment! I attached the entire controller code and error log. Please check it again. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

- First of all, there is no problem with matches().
- If you look at the three key error log lines above, they are as follows.

```java
at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:141) ~[spring-security-core-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:182) ~[spring-security-core-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
at com.JJoINT.CamPuzl.global.auth.service.AuthServiceImpl.login(AuthServiceImpl.java:64) ~[main/:na]
```

- First, an exception occurs in AuthServiceImpl.login, that is, line 64.

  - So it's not a problem with matches.
- Second, let’s look inside AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.

  - UsernameNotFoundException is thrown.
  - And it is caught and BadCredentialException is thrown.

```java
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        Assert.isInstanceOf(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class, authentication, () -> {
            return this.messages.getMessage("AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.onlySupports", "Only UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken is supported");
        });
        String username = this.determineUsername(authentication);
        boolean cacheWasUsed = true;
        UserDetails user = this.userCache.getUserFromCache(username);
        if (user == null) {
            cacheWasUsed = false;

            try {
                    //caused exception this method!
                user = this.retrieveUser(username, (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken)authentication);
            } catch (UsernameNotFoundException ex) {
                this.logger.debug("Failed to find user '" + username + "'");
                if (!this.hideUserNotFoundExceptions) {
                    throw ex;
                }
                                // your exception!
                throw new BadCredentialsException(this.messages.getMessage("AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials", "Bad credentials"));
            }

            Assert.notNull(user, "retrieveUser returned null - a violation of the interface contract");
        }
```

So now let's look at the retrieveUser method.

```java
@Override
    protected final UserDetails retrieveUser(String username, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication)
            throws AuthenticationException {
        prepareTimingAttackProtection();
        try {
            UserDetails loadedUser = this.getUserDetailsService().loadUserByUsername(username);
            if (loadedUser == null) {
                throw new InternalAuthenticationServiceException(
                        "UserDetailsService returned null, which is an interface contract violation");
            }
            return loadedUser;
        }
        catch (UsernameNotFoundException ex) {
            mitigateAgainstTimingAttack(authentication);
            throw ex;
        }
        catch (InternalAuthenticationServiceException ex) {
            throw ex;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new InternalAuthenticationServiceException(ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
    }
```

- Then why does UsernameNotFoundException occur?

  - Reason: Thrown **if an UserDetailsService implementation cannot locate a User by its username**.
    Author: Ben Alex
- It is likely that UserDetailsService is not implemented correctly.

  - Please override loadByUsername() of UserDetailsService and apply it to Security Config.
  - However, there are many variables so this may not solve your problem.
  - It would be helpful to debug as in the above process.
- Additionally, if you implement the Login API like the questioner's code, you do not need to use authenticationManager.

  - There is also a way to authenticate by issuing an AccessToken to HttpServletResponse and then parsing the JWT in Security.
  - If you want to make the most of Security, you can extend Security's Filter, implement the method to fit your service, and then apply it to the filter.
  - There are many Best Practices, so please search.

I hope it will be of help. thank you :)